# RxJava Default value for throttleFirst

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java, observable, reactive-programming

How to provide a default value for `throttleFirst` when the source observable doesn't emit anything in the given timespan?

```
ob1.throttleFirst(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

I have tried `defaultIfEmpty()` but I doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can't, that requires a custom operator.

Comment: Have you tried [merging](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) source observable with [interval](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html) of default values?